# Should this variable be local or static?

Tags: java, variables

I'm a beginner in Java trying to learn it and sorry if the question sounds dumb :D

Right now I'm making this simple program (without objects) for practice purpose, which generates random elements for the array using `Random randomNumber = new Random();`, all 3 methods (random: byte int, long elements), uses the same randomNumber variable.
**My question:** should the randomNumber variable created as static variable (by my knowledge it means that it will be in memory until execution of the program ends, is it true?), or local variable that is created every time we call one of those 3 methods (and destroyed after exiting them)? I'm trying to work on this task without objects just for practice purposes.

Thanks for help !

Comment: randomNumber is just an instance of random, it's not the number. big difference. also: class level, whether it is static or instance,is not the same as 'global'. "until it's somehow destroyed": do you think this happens by magic, or there is logic behind it?

Comment: Yes, i fixed that in my question, thanks. Instance variables are those that you need to create "instance (object)" of class, and static variables are the global variables that you can access with the class name. So should I make the variable in methods or just make one global (static) and use it? Is it true that the static variable will be there in memory until we end execution of the program ?

Comment: There are no globals in Java, but there are other scopes you haven't considered.

Comment: So what would be best practice making that variable static or local in methods?

Comment: @Lukas Java doesn't support global variables. why only looking at 'static or local'? why not an instance variable? your design depends on your requirements. we don't know your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely your choice. Your program will function the same way. The only difference is at the memory and processing power level.

Will you call many methods that use randomNumber in a row? Then don't destroy it and let it be an instance variable.

Do you plan on calling such a function every once in a while? Then don't keep the object in memory, let it be vreated only when you need it and destroy it afterwards (use it as a local variable).

Comment: Thank you, so let's say I call a method C from Class A (which uses static variable D in Class A) into Class B main method, will the static variable D destroyed after exiting method or will it be only destroyed when Class B main method execution ends ?

Comment: If you make it static (but you don't have to), the object will be destroyed when the program ends.

Comment: Thank you, so the static variable will be destroyed only when program ends.

Comment: One more question because I can't private message you. When I call method generateRandomElements(test) (test - array that i passed for random elements), it assigns the elements for "test" array without doing: test = generateRandomElements(test), could you explain me why it assigns the elements if i didn't add "test = ..." at the beginning?

Comment: sure. the object reference is passed as parameter, and so any change you make is done on the object itself, not on a copy of it, and of course it reflects in the method that called this one.

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to get the logic here, I'm not using any objects in this task, i just call the generation method from class A to class B main method :D

Comment: arrays are objects in Java, that was what I was referring to